# What does the string "";} /*B6D1B1EE*/ ?>" at the top of my Joomla page mean?

Tags: joomla

The following comment fragment appears to be popping up at the top of every page of the local government page I'm administrating:

[image: Fragment in action]

The site runs of the Joomla! framework, and I've gone through the header sections of each page and found nothing amiss. A quick Google search of

```
'";} /*B6D1B1EE*/ ?>'
```

reveals that I'm not alone in experiencing this problem:

[image: Google Search results, showing several pages that contain this string]

I'm surprised that I've never heard of this before. If you have any ideas on what might be causing this and how I might go about fixing it, they would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just an aside, I have had strings like that show up in php code in Wordpress and is usually something for a cookie to check and evaluate. In my case, it was for malicious coding used for a pharma hack. They embed code deep into your site and you might need to do a deep clean. Might be worth checking. Like I said, just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason PHP code is being sent to the browser. It may be that PHP is not enabled n that server but that page contains some. It could be short tags are used but the server has not enabled it. It could be poorly written code. But you need to get to the source code to find the ultimate root cause.

Comment: John, he's running joomla so I'm guessing php is enabled. Why do you say that's php code?

Comment: Between the comments and closing PHP tag I'd say it's a good match for PHP.

Comment: I cannot read the comment you left for me, as the post as been deleted. You can meet me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq to discuss, that would be easier and that is the place from where I review potential spam.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you could delete the `";} /*B6D1B1EE*/ ?>` snippet from the index.php file contained in your template folder.

More information could be found for the same issue here:
http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=933020

It could be that sites running a 1.5 version of Joomla were hacked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Joomla 1.5 websites without the Session Hardening and File Upload Security patches are being hacked.

These patches can be found at: https://docs.joomla.org/Security_hotfixes_for_Joomla_EOL_versions

According to [MiscCoder](http://forum.joomla.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=800594) at http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=933020#p3425599 clean up involves removing the file at `/modules/mod_stat/statXXX.php`, deleting files in the `/tmp` folder and cleaning up the files with "B6D1B1EE" in them although I haven't been able to verify this yet.

I'd be inclined to run a security audit using a commercial service such as [myjoomla.com](http://myjoomla.com) or [sucuri.net](http://sucuri.net) or similar to double check all compromised and modified files have been identified and fixed.